# MoCA adapter setup - mind boggling networking

Tags: networking, ethernet, wired-networking

I want to set up a MoCA adapter for wired internet in another room, but I have no idea how to make sense of the panel containing all of the networking gear…

The picture I attached is what’s behind the panel (located in the living room). The router is connected to an Ethernet port in the wall on the opposite end of the living room.

The room I want Ethernet in currently only has a coax cable, hence the need for a MoCA setup (I’ve tried powerline, it doesn’t work great).

The internet was (and still is) provided for free by the previous building manager - he’s no longer around and cannot help.

I have 2 MoCA adapters on the way.

Can anyone help with this? This setup is not familiar at all to me. Appreciated!

Edit: I should mention, lights 8, 6, and 5 are lit up green. If I unplug my router from the Ethernet port, light number 6 turns off. I should also mention that I’m living in an apartment - and I used to share this internet connection with people in another unit. I’m not sure if that’s the case anymore. My assumption is that I should be doing something with line 6.

[image: Networking Gear]

Comment: Why are you at the apartment building's panel instead of setting up the adapter within your own apartment?

Comment: This is in my apartment.